# Instalacion de phonegap-facebook-plugin dudas

Tags: ionic, facebook, phonegap, login

Estoy siguiendo el siguiente tutorial para instalar el phonegap-facebook-plugin con Ionic

https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/native-facebook-login-with-ionic-framework

Pude hacerlo funcionar en browser con algunas modificaciones, pero nunca pude hacerlo funcionar en mi android con la APP de cordova para conectarse por wifi al server de mi pc… no me anda el boton de login, cosa que en browser si me anda… mi duda surge a la hora de instalar el plugin creo que estoy haciendo algo mal, ya que no me guarda el nombre y el ID de la app de facebook en ningun archivo lo instalo mediante el siguiente comando:

```
cordova -d plugin add phonegap-facebook-plugin –variable APP_ID=”123456789″–variable APP_NAME=”myApplication”
```

Lo ejecuto con las comillas en el ID y el APP NAME e igual creo que no me lo esta instalando, calculo que por ahi viene mi error, por eso no me compila el plugin cuando lo quiero ejecutar en el celular y no me anda el boton de login, mi pregunta es, donde o como configuro mi ID y nombre de APP en el config.xml? en algun otro file?

Saludos y desde ya muchas gracias!